# element loses hover attribute if clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
var rem = 0;

$('#labrem').on('click', function(){
 if(rem == 0){$(this).css('background', 'white'); rem = 1;}
 else{$(this).css('background', '#eee'); rem = 0;}
});
```

```css
.labrem{background:#eee;cursor:pointer;}
.labrem:hover{background:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='labrem' id='labrem'>remember me</div>
```

Firstly hover the mouse over `rem` to see - hover works.

Then click twice on `rem` and hover the mouse again - hover doesn't work.

What is the holy secret here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by using inline styles. When clicking the element twice the background will be set to either `#eee` or `white`. Because `inline styles` override `css rules` the `:hover` never gets applied.

To be able to persist the `white` classes can be used:

```js
$('#labrem').on('click', function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('activated')
});
```

```css
.labrem{background:#eee;cursor:pointer;}
.labrem:hover{background:white;}

.activated{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='labrem' id='labrem'>remember me</div>
```

Comment: so if you change the style for `normal` state  - it takes precedence over `hover` state. Vey strange.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant. Are you referring to the inline styles or css rules? CSS rules have varying specificity. The default is the order, selectors that come later override selectors that are specified earlier. Then the more specific an selector is(`.labrem:hover` is more specific than `.labrem`) can override the order of the css rules. @qadenza

Comment: My point is - clicking on `rem` - it's `normal` style is changed and not `hover` style. Hover style is untouched and it must not be the  object of any `precedence`.

Comment: You can clear the inline styles by using `$(this).css('background', '')` this will allow the `:hover` css to be applied again. @qadenza

Comment: useful, thanks, but nonsense regarding taking a precedence over something not included in procedure at all - remains. Why people call this - `taking precedence` why not - `a bag`.

Answer (score 1):

inline style takes higher precedence than class selector ( specificity )

when you click once the value or `rem` is set equal to `1`, now when you click second time it goes to else condition and set the background to `#eee` and you don't see hover effect as inline style takes higher precedence than class selector